# Remiander except 0

Tags: computer-science

I know this is a simple question but I am thinking if there is a better way to do so.

I want to calculate the value of a deck of cards.
Every card is associated with a number, i.e. there are 1 to 52 cards.
I would like to extract the value of a card from a number.

The naive approach would get remainders. For example, 12 = 12 mod 13 or 14 = 1 mod 13.

But it does not work for 13, 26, 39, 52. Is there a simple way to get 13 instead of 0? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand.  Go ahead and number every card $1$ to $52$ if you want.  Lots of times people set $2\clubsuit$ to $1$ and $A\spadesuit$ to $52$, but you could assign numbers differently if you prefer.  What's the problem?

Comment: Are you asking:  "If we number the cards in the usual way, can we recover the rank from the number in a simple way?"  To which, the answer is, as you say, take the remainder (not the reminder) $\pmod {13}$.  If you get a $0$, then the card is an Ace.  If you get a $12$, the card is a King.  And so on.

Comment: The card is in order. ♣ 1-13 then follow by ♠1-13, etc. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Using reminder can get the value I want except 13, 26, 39, 52, i.e. the Kings

Comment: So, you are calling an Ace, $1$?  Unusual, but fine.  there is still no problem. If you get a $0$, then it is a King.  If you get a $12$, it is a Queen, and so on.  And, really, the word is "remainder" not "reminder".

Comment: If you really want a formula instead of just writing an if-else statement, use ((n-1) mod 13)+1 to yield a number from 1 to 13.

Comment: Thank you. Greg. This is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: lulu. Thanks for the reminder. lol

Comment: This question makes no sense.